# Query with GROUP_CONCAT is taking more time in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I have three tables Order ,Address , OrderLines.

The following is  Order Table

```
orderId | item      |
 1      |  TextBook |
 1      |  Ipad     |
```

The following is  Address Table

```
orderId | Adress      |
 1      | Florida.    |
 2      | Seattle.    |
```

The following is  OrderLines Table

```
orderId | likeKey  | lineValue
 1      | likeKey1 | lineValue1
 1      | likeKey2 | lineValue2
 2      | likeKey3 | lineValue3
 2      | likeKey4 | lineValue4
```

I want to create output file with the above table's data in a file.
the file should be as follows: LineDetails should have json format of OrderLines table valuee

```
orderId | item      | Adress  | LineDetails
 1      | TextBook. | Florida | {"likeKey1:"lineValue1","likeKey2:"lineValue2"}
 2      | Ipad.     | Seattle | {"likeKey3:"lineValue3","likeKey4:"lineValue4"}
```

Following is the query which i have tried , but its taking somuch time. Is there anything wrong in my query?
I have 1TB's of data in each table;

```
   select a.id, b.address, CONCAT("{",GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT("\"",e.testKey,"\":"), CONCAT("\"",e.testvalue,"\"")),"}")  order a INNER JOIN address b ON a.orderId=b.orderId  INNER JOIN orderlines e.orderId = b.orderId  INTO OUTFILE '/datadrive/tmp/testfile.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ;
```

Comment: Indeed you have really large tables. Could you try to do the export in batches? Using the conditions `WHERE orderId > 0 AND orderId < 1000000`, `WHERE orderId > 1000001 AND orderId < 2000000`, etc

Comment: @Silvanu thank you , i will try this one.